# MySQL not querying primary key

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I'm confused with MySQL. I'm querying a table with a primary key field called `index`.

`SELECT * FROM content WHERE index = 7`

Pretty simple right? I keep getting a syntax error though, around `index = 7`, error number 1064 (can't paste the error as it's on an iPhone simulator).

The field `index` contains a 7. It is the `PRIMARY_KEY`, and of type `int(6)`

The database works fine querying other fields and so on.

Are there settings I need to ensure are in place before I can query this field?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Most probably because `index` is read as a keyword!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE `index` = 7
```

`index` is a reserved word in MySQL. You have to escape it with backticks. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: I think I just had an "a-ha moment". Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another suitable workaround (for a column identifier which is a reserved word) is to qualify the column with the table name or a table alias. My preference is to always use a table alias. In this example, we give the table `content` an alias of `c`, which we can then reference in the query:

```
SELECT c.* FROM content c WHERE c.index = 7
```

In this example, backticks are not required around the column name, because when it is qualified with a table alias, MySQL sees it as an identifier; a reserved word can't be qualified with a table name.

Using a table alias is a pattern we use in more complex statements, which reference multiple tables and/or reference the same table multiple times. Nothing prevents us from using the same pattern with simple statements.

And the backticks around identifiers is always allowed, even if they are required:

```
SELECT `c`.* FROM `content` `c` WHERE `c`.`index` = 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Index is a reserved word, use

```
Select * from content 
where `index` = 7
```